# How do I extract ints in R vectors?

Tags: r, vector

I'm trying to extract a specific index in a vector, and I keep getting a strange output. I'm using R-Studio and it works fine with string vectors, but I get strange numbers with an "L" after them when I input integers. The same thing happens when I define `all_numbers` using `c()`, `:`, and `seq()`. Am I doing something incorrectly? I thought I was doing it exactly as my textbook describes it.

```r
# Extracts "Anne" correctly
all_names <- c("Sally", "Pedro", "Anne", "Molly")
extract <- all_names [3]

# Extracts "3L" not 3
all_numbers <- 1:30
extract <- all_numbers[3]

# Extracts "7L" not 7
all_numbers <- 5:30
extract <- all_numbers[3]

# Extracts "12L" not 12
all_numbers <- 10:30
extract <- all_numbers[3]
```

Comment: Although I don't get `L` in `extract` but `L` is a way in which R represent integers. Check `class(1L)` and `class(1)`. Also I don't know why you expect 8 and 13 in 2nd and 3rd case when 3rd value in `all_numbers` is 7 and 12 respectively.

Comment: Thank you! Why would they be 7 and 12? Does it start at index 1 instead of index 0?

Comment: R starts indexing at 1. There is no `all_numbers[0]`

Comment: Oh okay, that at least clears up one problem! I'm now finding that having an integer without an "L" at the end apparently creates a double vector, which takes up more data. However, I'm still looking for how to remove it from an output.

Comment: @RonakShah I found out my issue - I'm using RStudio, and I was looking in "Environment" instead of printing to the console. When I do the latter, the "L" doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`L` is a way in which R represents integers.

```
class(1L)
#[1] "integer"

class(1)
#[1] "numeric"
```

In R, indexing starts at 1. So `all_numbers[3]` in 2nd and 3rd case should be 7 and 12 respectively.

I can't find the relevant document at this moment but if I remember correctly integer takes up less space than numeric class.

If you don't want `L` in the output convert `all_numbers` to numeric class.

```
all_numbers <- as.numeric(all_numbers)
```